# Passing array as reference to function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void counter(int input[], int *output);

int main()
{
    int input[15], output[10] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        cin >> input[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << i << " appears " << counter(input[], output[]) << " times in the input." << endl;

    return 0;
}

void counter(int input[], int *output){
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        switch(input[i]){
            case 1:
                output[0]++;
            case 2:
                output[1]++;
            case 3:
                output[2]++;
            case 4:
                output[3]++;
            case 5:
                output[4]++;
            case 6:
                output[5]++;
            case 7:
                output[6]++;
            case 8:
                output[7]++;
            case 9:
                output[8]++;
            case 10:
                output[9]++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm writing a function where I have to pass an array as a reference to it, there are no errors, but when I try to read the elements in the main function, they are all 0 as initially initialized.

Comment: That was from a previous incarnation of the posted code. But the latest won't compile. Don't edit sample code on the fly. Create the smallest sample you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem, then post that.

Comment: I call it `counter (input, output)` and I get an error - no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<'.

Comment: function returns void and you wanna print it ?

Comment: and you are not calling the function with right parameters, too

Comment: Your current sample code does not call `counter(input,output)`. Post the code that you're compiling. Otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `counter()` function (which you could write in much fewer lines -- that's an exercise for later) returns void.

So:

```
 cout < counter(foo, bar)
```

Does not print the contents of either array. It would print `void`, if that made sense. But since that doesn't make sense, it's a compile error.

You probably want:

```
// fill input
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    cin >> input[i];

// fill output
counter(input,output);

// print contents of output
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << i << " appears " << output[i] << " times in the input." << endl;
```

Comment: That seems to work, however.. there is a problem with the value of output[i], it seems to be the same for each element. It never resets?

Comment: @user3002211 Well, you also forgot to `break` in that `switch` inside each `case`

Comment: @user3002211 well spotted. And (as I hinted) there's no need for a `switch` anyway. `case 1: foo[0]; case 2: foo[1] ...` -- spot a pattern there? Perhaps something mathsy?

Comment: as a further hint... there is a bug in the last line of my example code, which an also be fixed with "something mathsy".

Comment: @slim u mean that in foo[x], x is -1 of the case so I can somehow make the code smaller rather than all the cases?

Comment: @user3002211 yep. `x = input[i]; foo[x-1]++` -- but you're gonna have to think about when input[i] <1 or >10!

Comment: Note there is a typo in your first code example - '<' should be '<<'.  StackOverflow won't let me do this as a suggested edit because only one character

Answer (score 1):

you did not use the function :D, please use it before printing :)

try this:

```
int main()
{
    int input[15], output[10] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        cin >> input[i];


    counter(input, output);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << i << " appears " << output[i] << " times in the input." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `counter(input[], output[])` ?

Comment: it was not there when i was posting ! :)

Comment: I call it `counter (input, output)` and I get an error - no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<'

Comment: because it returns void and you try to print void, compiler can't make it pass because it makes no sense

Comment: sorry for my weird answers but the code was changing like every second